# How to use gifs in a forum avoiding code injection

Tags: xss, code-injection

To prevent code injection in my forum I´m using this function, although I know that it is still insecure:

```
function evitamos_script($texto) {

    $limpia = strip_tags($texto, '<b> <i> <u> <quote> <img> <center> <code> <cite> <div> <a> <blockquote>'); //EVITAMOS SCRIPTS

    return $limpia;
}
```

Embed gifs use `<iframe>` tags so I cannot make them run. Is there a way to let specific kind of iframes be written or do I have to do ir in another way?